# JAVA: What does it mean to map string keys?

Tags: java, hashmap, mapping, hashtable

I have been given this assignment where the instructor has asked us to

```
    //Create a hash table where the initial storage
   //is 7 and string keys can be mapped to Q values
```

My question is what does mapping a string to a Q value mean? Im sorry if this is a simple question, but im very new to this.

Also, im not sure if it will change the answer or not, but in the code we can not use any Java Collections library so i have to code this from scratch

Answer (score 4):

So First point create `HashMap` with initial storage 7, below line creates `HashMap` with initial capacity 7 which accepts `String` type key and `String` type value

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(7);
```

Example to add key value to `HashMap`

```
map.put("hello", "world");
```

According to you need to create `HashMap` with `String` type key and `Q` type value, so i believe `Q` must be class or interface

```
HashMap<String, Q> map = new HashMap<String, Q>(7);
```

**Note: hashmap will override value for duplicate keys**

If you don't want to use Collections for this, then you should create `CustomHashMap` with implementation

```
class HashMapCustom<K, V> {

 private Entry<K,V>[] table;   //Array of Entry.
 private int capacity= 7;  //Initial capacity of HashMap

 static class Entry<K, V> {
     K key;
     V value;
     Entry<K,V> next;

     public Entry(K key, V value, Entry<K,V> next){
         this.key = key;
         this.value = value;
         this.next = next;
     }
 }

public HashMapCustom(){
   table = new Entry[capacity];
}
```

In the above code by default initial capacity is 7 `HashMapCustom<String, Q> hashMapCustom = new HashMapCustom<String, Q>();`

But still you need to write your own logic for `put`, `delete`, `get` and the methods you need. i suggest you to check this [ref1](https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-custom-implementation),[ref2](https://www.jeejava.com/creating-custom-hashmap-in-java/)